# How to delete/set "null" nested property of state array in ReactJs Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, state

For example I have a site (location, not website). Under that there are 4 more "levels" of specification. For example lvl 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 can be "USA - New York - Brooklyn - streetX" or "CompanyA - buildingA - floorC - roomNumber".

I have to be able to delete the "lowest" specification level. So if you want to delete the roomNumber, because you moved an item to another room, floor etc... Only "roomNumber" should be deleted but "CompanyA - buildingA - floorC" should still exist in the state.

My API will return the last "level" so the record (with ID) of whatever is associated with "roomNumber". So, I have the ID to delete.

This is how my state looks:

[image]

So for example, I want to remove "lvl4test" level. Back-end wise I just send the ID, it deletes the record and on page-refresh (forced F5) it will realize this level is gone. But now in my reducer I don't know how to do it.

Here's my reducer:

```
case DELETE_SITE: {
      console.log("delete site reducer reached");
      return {
        ...state,
        // somehow makes all "siteRows" == "undefined"
        siteRows: state.siteRows.map((s) => {
          if (s.siteLevel2Id && s.siteLevel2Id == action.payload.id) 
            s.siteLevel2Id = null;
          if (s.siteLevel3Id && s.siteLevel3Id == action.payload.id) 
            s.siteLevel3Id = null;
          if (s.siteLevel4Id && s.siteLevel4Id == action.payload.id) 
            s.siteLevel4Id = null;
          if (s.siteLevel5Id && s.siteLevel5Id == action.payload.id) 
            s.siteLevel5Id = null;
         })
      }
    }
```

If I do this, it will make all "siteRows" as "undefined" when React's trying to refresh?
I don't know if I should use "filter" but don't know how to do so on nested objects/foreach objects and then filter on their properties etc...

Basically, all I want is "siteLevel4Name" and "siteLevel4Id" to be "null" as well and then React refreshing state and my webpage. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: in "action.payload" I get the item I want to delete, so "action.payload.id" for deleting "lvl4test" will be "d117c1f6-..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) have to return value, not just modify it. You return nothing, hence the undefined. At the end of your mapping function you should return new `s` value.

```js
function reducer(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    siteRows: state.siteRows.map((s) => {
      if (s.siteLevel2Id && s.siteLevel2Id == action.payload.id)
        return { ...s, siteLevel2Id: null };
      if (s.siteLevel3Id && s.siteLevel3Id == action.payload.id)
        return { ...s, siteLevel3Id: null };
      if (s.siteLevel4Id && s.siteLevel4Id == action.payload.id)
        return { ...s, siteLevel4Id: null };
      if (s.siteLevel5Id && s.siteLevel5Id == action.payload.id)
        return { ...s, siteLevel5Id: null };
      return s;
    }),
  };
}
```