# How to delete/replace `null` objects/properties using `.filter()` from payload in redux reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

So far, I have implemented a small *todoapp* that uses redux and reactjs.
However, I added some functionalities like **adding**, **delete**, **resetting**, and **updating** todos, the error sometimes doesn't show, when I do like this `<Todo key={todo} todo={todo} />;` but when I don't do then those errors comes...

Below I shared some snippets:

> Todo.js

```
const Todo = ({ todo, id }) => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(todo);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  let  taskContent = (
      <>
        {edit}
        <button onClick={() => setInputEdit(true)}>edit</button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "RESET_ACTION" })}>
          reset
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <li
      key={id}
      style={{ listStyle: "none", display: "flex", marginTop: "20px" }}
    >
      {taskContent}
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch(deleteTodo(id))}
        style={{ marginLeft: "30px", paddingTop: "0px" }}
      >
        delete
      </button>
    </li>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: state.id
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
    addTodo: (id, text) => dispatch(addTodo(id, text))
  };
};

...
```

> TodoList.js

```
import { connect, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Todo from "./Todo";

const TodoList = () => {
  const todoList = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
  return (
    <ul>
      {todoList && todoList.length
        ? todoList.map((todo) => {
            <Todo key={todo} todo={todo} />;
          })
        : "no todos yet"}
    </ul>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, { payload }) => {
  const { todos } = state;
  return {
    ...todos,
    todos: payload
  };
};

...
```

> actions.js

```
import { ADD_TODO } from "../actions/todoaction";

let nextTodoId = 0;
export const addTodo = () => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  payload: {
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text: title.value
  }
});

export const RESET_ACTION = {
  type: "RESET"
};
```

> AddTodo.js

```
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "../actions/actions";

const AddTodo = ({ id }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", marginTop: "20px" }}>
      ...
      <input
        type="text"
        id="title"
        name="title"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => {
          addTodo({ id, text: setText(e.target.value) });
        }}
        placeholder="Enter Title..."
      />
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(addTodo(id, text), setText(""))}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addTodo: (id, text) => dispatch(addTodo(id, text))
  };
};

...
```

> todos.js (reducer):

```
import {
  ADD_TODO,
  RESET_TODO
} from "../actions/todoaction";

const initialtodoState = {
  todos: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "this is text"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "this is 2text"
    }
  ]
};

const todos = (state = initialtodoState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {
      return { ...state, todos: [...state.todos, action.payload] };
    }
    
    case RESET_TODO: { // can I remove/replace null objects here or how I can do it?
      return state.todos;
    }
    ...
  }
};

export default todos;
```

The given below error shows me since yesterday :(

> error:

[image: Console error:]

> This is what the Redux Devtools shows me:

[image: Redux Devtools]

> Console output:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

1. I couldn't delete/remove `null` properties and even tried to replace them but still faced this issue.
2. As I know, the error caused due to `text` but when I add `todo. text` it shows...

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
    at https://5y0swi-3000.csb.app/main.683e9f6e5ed288abfe49.hot-update.js:37:15
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at TodoList (https://5y0swi-3000.csb.app/main.683e9f6e5ed288abfe49.hot-update.js:34:78)
```

or otherwise, shows blank/no todos. Also, When I try to return `<Todo />` still shows the same :(

##### **What I want**:

1. I don't need those `null` objects/properties nested in `todos` which is inside of `payload`, instead of that I need `todos`'s `text` contained in the array *(in other words, I want to replace them)*.
2. Whenever I refresh the browser, it should show the initialization todos that already exists in the `todos array` with the newly added `todos`.

**Note:**  The given below was the only *stack question* I found, but that doesn't help me because they didn't use `.filter()` to remove the `null` nested property, instead they use `.map()` to `delete/remove` it.

- [How to delete set null nested property of state array in reactjs redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549958/how-to-delete-set-null-nested-property-of-state-array-in-reactjs-redux)

I guess the error was caused due to `null` objects inside the `todo` array, but don't know what I'm missing. Or is there any way to get the issue solved?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's a huge chunk of code. Can you try to minimize it to only include relevant code?

Comment: Hi, I removed some unrelevant codes, please check it if the issue is clarifying to you?

Comment: Maybe you could try this `<Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />;` And it seems you're not passing any arguments where you export your `addTodo`

Comment: Hi, I tried to pass that `<Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />;` but it says `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')` You know I'm still trying to resolve my issue but still couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: It is actually showing me `null` objects in my `todos` array don't know what is the problem and how to solve it...  . I tried to destroy using `RESET_TODO`, still doesn't work.  **please help me or give any suggestions...!!** *I feel sometimes like I am playing with those errors :(((*

Comment: Try not to use `useDispatch` and `mapDispatchToProps` at the same time. Stick with `useDispatch` and `useSelector` only if you have function components anyway. Not sure if this is the source of your error though.

Comment: Hi, @timotgl I was active here in stackoverflow to give you a reply but I couldn't cause I was drastically solving my issue on my own since yesterday whole day so that, I could understand the *errors* and *logic behind it*, However, I tried to reduce my code in ques. maybe it will clarify to you all, **but thanku to you all guys for giving suggestions and helping me (^^)**  BTW, your suggestions help me and it works well as expected and somewhat I did some changes to work as well!! Thank you so much!